# Entity Framework 4 - Joining SQL View with IQueryable<T> Repository

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, navigation-properties

If i have the following `IQueryable<T>` Repository:

```
public class OrderRepository : GenericRepository<Order>, IOrderRepository
{
   public IQueryable<Order> Find()
   {
       return Context.CurrentEntitySet;
   }
}
```

And i use it like this to get a particular order:

```
var order = orderRepository.Find().SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderId == 1);
```

All is fine.

Now, i have a SQL Server 2008 View called **OrderDetailsView**, which i have added to my EDMX. It has a field called **OrderId** which i want to join on. It's a **1-1** between **Order** and **OrderDetailsView**.

I want to return a particular Order, and the corresponding OrderDetailsView record.

I'm not sure what the correct approach here is.

- Can i have a navigational property to the View on my Order entity? I can add the association - but the designer is complaining about it not being mapped - i'm assuming it requires a FK, but obviously a View cannot have a FK.
- Do i need to do an explicit join? If so, that means they are independant entities with no association, so i would require another Repository - and i'd need two database calls, as you can't perform a JOIN across two repositories.

**Ideally,** i would like to do this:

```
return ctx.Orders.Include("OrderDetailsView").SingleOrDefault();
```

But as mentioned, i don't know if it's possible to add a navigational property that points to a View.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it - i needed to add a **Referential Constraint** (since there is no FK):

[image]

Now i can eager load the view like any other nav.

Well that was easier than i thought! :)